# Hadoop Secondary NameNode IP Address

Tags: hadoop

I need to write a java code that fetches the IP Address of the Secondary Namenode for a given cluster. Given the IP address of the Namenode for the given cluster.

I am able to get the report for the Datanodes and the Namenode but cannot find a way to get the IP address for the Secondary Namenode.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

String hostURL = conf.get(new String("dfs.secondary.http.address"));

where conf is a configuration object and hostURL will be hostname:portnumber port number will be 50090 by default

Answer (score 1):

If you have a copy of the configuration files (as detailed in @debarshi's answer), then you can use that to extract the address, otherwise the namenode has no knowledge of the secondary name node - more so the secondary name node contacts the name node to get the image and edits, merges them and then posts them back.

I guess you could inspect the job.xml of a job that is running / has run, and parse out the configuration value too.